# Find, in linear time, duplicate in array of length N, numbers 1 to N-1 without using additional obj/arr to keep track of a count

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I was able to complete this edabit challenge in linear time and space, but the challenge says it can be completed only using the same array (no need for an additional obj/arr to keep track of 'already seen' numbers.) and *in linear time*.

constraints: a list of length 'n' and numbers ranging from 1 to n-1

```
// length N
// 1 to N - 1
const l = [5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2]

function findDuplicate(list) {
  
}
```

I think it's something related to keeping track of the number 'already seen' at its index in the array, but I can't quite to that without needing to loop once again over the array.

This is how I was able to do it:

```
function findDuplicate(list) {
  const dict = {}
  for (let i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
    dict[list[i]] = dict[list[i]] + 1 || 1   
    if (dict[list[i]] === 2) return list[i]
  }
}
```

But I'm using an `obj` to keep track of 'already seen` numbers.

Comment: Hmm, you can sort the array and then iterate through it starting with index 1. If the current number in the array is the same as `numbers[i - 1]` then this is your duplicate.

Comment: sorry, forgot to say it needs to be linear time. will add that to question

Comment: You could get the sum of the array elements and subtract it with `n*(n+1)/2`, the sum of natural numbers. (or, in this case `n*(n-1)/2`). But, that would need a variable. Does that work?

Comment: Is there only one duplicate in your array?

Comment: only one duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an array of natural numbers with exactly one duplicate, you could get the sum of natural numbers till `n-1` and subtract it from the sum of array elements.

```
(5 + 2 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 2) - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) = 2
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
function findDuplicate(list) {
  const n = list.length,
        sum = list.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
        naturalSum = n * (n-1) / 2

  return sum - naturalSum
}

console.log( findDuplicate([5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2]) )
console.log( findDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 3]) )
```

You can write it without using extra variables if that's not allowed as well:

```
function findDuplicate(l) {
  return l.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) - (l.length * (l.length - 1) / 2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const numbers = [5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2];
const n = numbers.length - 1;
const expectedSum = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
const sum = numbers.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
const duplicate = sum - expectedSum ;
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe `[5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2].reduce((acc, num, index) => (acc + num) - index, 0)`